# CSS ::Before on Table Cell

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I want to add a `::before` selector on some table cells what has a `position:absolute` , but it fails:

```css
table{ border:1px solid #ccc; padding:10px; }
table td{ border:1px solid #ccc; padding:5px; }

.useBefore::before{
  content:'before';
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<table>
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td>bird</td>
           <td>animal</td>
           <td>nature</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='useBefore'>
           <td>building</td>
           <td>robot</td>
           <td>city</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

I noticed that if I add the `::before` to all of the `tr`'s then it works:

```css
table{ 
    border:1px solid #ccc; 
    padding:10px;
  }
  table td{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding:5px;
  }
  
  tr::before{
    content:'before';
    position:absolute;
  }
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>bird</td>
        <td>animal</td>
        <td>nature</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class='useBefore'>
        <td>building</td>
        <td>robot</td>
        <td>city</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

But this is not what I want, because I want to add it only on some of them.

Comment: Why do you have two colons before, *ahem*, `before`?

Comment: well, it looks cool, sry I edit it :D

Comment: It works fine for me in FF5. Maybe you need to define "fails" a bit more clearly?

Comment: @Wesley Murch I used the latest Chrome, Firefox 3.6, I edited the snippet again because I screwed up some things there so maybe you've seen that, please check it again.

Comment: @CIRK: Oh, the *positioning* fails, not the appearance of `:before` content.

Comment: @Wesley Murch , yup, that was the problem

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Because double colons are the CSS3 pseudo-element notation. Except IE (< 9 I believe) doesn't understand them.

Comment: @BoltClock - Hmm. Is it a change, or simply another way? What's the difference?

Comment: @Jared Farrish: They introduced the new notation to make it easier to tell pseudo-classes from pseudo-elements, but single colons are still OK for compatibility with older pseudo-elements: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements

Comment: @BoltClock - Well, that's interesting. Not sure why we need content in the style, but hey, I'm just in the cheap seats. :D

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm not sure why it fails exactly, but you could add it on the first table cell instead.

```
  .useBefore td:first-child:before{
    content:'before';
    position:absolute;
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure why is your code working, but it works :)) I tried `table tr .useBefore` but that failed, hey thanks very much! :) your name sounds like a dirty word in hungarian are you hungarian :P ?

Comment: @CIRK Yeah some other people told me before that my name is not nice in Hungarian :).

Comment: I was having the same problem, and noticed that using `:before` on the `tr` was doing something like inserting a new cell before the first one, and pushing all other cells to the side. Using the pseudo-element on the `td:first-child` worked just fine.

Comment: @AdamHalasz When you write `table tr .useBefore`, it means an element *inside* of a `tr` that has the classname `.useBefore`. If you mean to affect a `tr` that is also a `.useBefore`, then you type `table tr.useBefore`.